# Implementing Github authentication with Firebase and Xcode (swift)

Tags: swift, github, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've been receiving this error **"An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information"** when trying to login through the access-token I receive from Github.

```
let credential = FIRGitHubAuthProvider.credentialWithToken(accessToken)
                        FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential) { (user, error) in
                            if let error = error { 
                                print(error.localizedDescription) 
                            }
                        }
```

It seems the issue is happening here but I'm not so sure why. Thank you in advance!